# How to get access to directory in Django

Tags: javascript, python, json, django

In `media/json` I have JSON files and I want to read them with a JavaScript file which is in `static/js` without hardcoding. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean how to get the JSON through an AJAX or similar mechanism which the JavaScript in question will deal with, then you probably want [JsonResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects) and a simple view that starts at an URL on your server and returns the JSON in question. The script will be loaded in some other view using a `<script src="http://wherever" />` tag. In a template you'll probably use `<script src="{% static "js/scriptname" %} />` See [managing static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/)

It's not clear what you mean "without hardcoding". The view can receive arguments through its URL and serve up the JSON that these arguments dictate.